# Load Keystore with null InputStream and password?

Tags: android, ssl, keystore

I came across (inherited) the following code:

```
String ksType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore ks   = KeyStore.getInstance(ksType);
ks.load(null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sockFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(ks);
```

I am confused by the call to the `KeyStore` `load` method.  What keystore is this code using?  I looked at the KeyStore documentation and as far as I can tell this is legitimate.

However, the code does not work.  The app takes a URL for the server to connect to.  The app throws `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate` errors - even if the site has a valid SSL certificate.

Debugging, I added the following line:

```
Log.v(TAG,"ks has " + String.valueOf(ks.size()) + " entries.");
```

to get the number of items in the keystore.  It returns zero.

I feel like I am grossly misunderstanding something about KeyStores.

Should this code work? What is it supposed to do?

**EDIT**
Based on how the code is being used (to authenticate websites) I believe it is being used as a truststore, not a keystore.  The `SSLSocketFactory` that is being used from `org.apache.http.conn.ssl`.  Looking at the resources for the app, there does not appear to be a keystore file included in the app.  Puzzling to me.

Comment: @EJP Updated question to include how the does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if it was being used as a keystore, but so would 'null'. It wouldn't work if it was being used as a truststore. Can you post the constructor of SSLSocketFactory that is being called?

EDIT: Any SSL client needs a non-empty truststore to be secure. The one supplied with Java is sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: My debugging code shows that I have an empty truststore.  How can I tell the code to use the one Java supplies?